# CDS option pricing in Quantlib Excel (QuantlibXL)

Tags: quantlib, cds

I am trying to price an index CDS option using QuantlibXL. Anyone aware of an existing template sheet or sample formula for creation of CDS and CDS objects? The sample template sheets provided with QuantlibXL do not cover creation of CDS and CDS option objects.

Also, I tried adapting the procedure described in the python quantlib stackexchange question...

[CDS Option pricing in quantlib python](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/55148/cds-option-pricing-in-quantlib-python)

...however the functions do not map one-to-one to QuantlibXL. E.g. QuantlibXL has no plain 'qlDate' nor 'qlYieldTermStructureHandle' functions. Thanks

Comment: May I humbly suggest not using Excel, and using Dom O'Kane's financepy in Python, which has `FinCDSIndexOption`. (See FinancePyManual.pdf 6,4)

Comment: Thanks Dimitri. FinancePy is in beta but handles CDS options and CDS Index options. See https://github.com/domokane/FinancePy. Look under notebooks for an example.

Comment: Thanks Dimitri and Dom, I was aware of quantlib python but unaware of FinancePy. On surface, the CDS option notebook there appears to be a good starting point, so I will try my hands on it. I guess when I hear the answer from the author of the book I referred to for CDS options, then it is time to make the switch!